# how to exec linux shell step by step with java

Tags: java, linux, shell

linux(centos 6):

step 1

```
$:yum install xxx
```

reture some message like

> **"Are you OK with your IP being logged? (Y)es/(N)o"**

step 2

```
$:Y
```

the install is going on.(other commands maybe have step 3)

but how can i execute this cammands with java?

this is my java code:

```
String[] commands = new String[]{"yum","install","xxx"};
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = run.exec(commands);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream());
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

the bf include

> "Are you OK with your IP being logged?"

Now how can i execute the command(`"Y"`) so that the install can going on

please help me.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/442088/how-do-you-answer-yes-for-yum-install-automatically

Comment: Is this a question about how to make `yum` operate without prompting, or more generally about how to supply input to a program you have launched using `Runtime.exec()`?

Comment: 'yum' command just a sample, maybe use other comands. I want to know how can i exec linux shell with java ,and this comands must input y/n or other.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can execute the command with a "y" (Yes) but instead you could run yum as follows

```
yum -y install xxx
```

> -y, --assumeyes
>   Assume yes; assume that the answer to any question which would be asked is yes.
>   Configuration Option: assumeyes
>   See: https://linux.die.net/man/8/yum

Comment: 'yum' command just a sample, maybe use other commands. I want to know how can i exec linux shell with java ,and this commands must input y/n or other Next step.

Comment: BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
     bw.write("Y");
     bw.newLine();
     bw.flush();